# How to convert multi-page Image bytes into PDF or TIFF bytes in memory with Python?

Tags: python, image, pdf, python-imaging-library

I am looking for a solution to convert Image bytes into PDF bytes **in memory only**.

For my web application, it takes in pdf/tiff documents (can be multi-paged) for information extraction.

I am adding in an image preprocessing step at the start of the pipeline. However, this step is only applicable for images as I am using OpenCV2. Thus, the pdf/tiff file is converted into image(s) for preprocessing. However, to send the file for information extraction I will need to join them back together, as there is a different logic flow for the first vs the subsequent pages.

I was previously using a workaround (referencing local path of merged pdf) but now I would like to remove the dependency and do everything **in-memory**. This is so that I will be able to deploy the application on the cloud.

```
image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(file_str))
num_frames = image.n_frames

# Loop through each page of a tif file
for i in range(num_frames):
    image.seek(i)
    file_array = np.array(image)
    file_array = file_array.astype(np.uint8) * 255

    # Preprocessing (removed for simplicity)

    # TODO: Merge back into PDF file
```

**Edit:**
Simple answer: I can't do this in memory. Instead, I have used the tempfile library to help me to save the files there and delete the temporary directory after I am done. That, in some way has helped to achieve the "in memory" aspect.

Answer (score 0):

[Writing (not reading) multi-page PDF files is possible using Pillow.](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#pdf) For the below solution, I used [`pdf2image`](https://pypi.org/project/pdf2image/) for converting some multi-page PDF file to a list of Pillow `Image` objects. So, please adapt that according to your existing code.

```py
from PIL import Image
import pdf2image
import numpy as np

# Read pages from PDF to Pillow Image objects
frames_in = pdf2image.convert_from_path('path/to/your/file.pdf')

# Enumerate frames, and preprocess
frames_out = []
for i, frame in enumerate(frames_in):

    # Convert to NumPy array
    frame = np.array(frame)

    # Preprocessing for the first page
    if i == 0:
        frame[:100, ...] = [255, 0, 0]

    # Preprocessing for the other pages
    else:
        frame[:100, ...] = [0, 0, 255]

    # Convert back to Pillow Image object, and append to output list
    frames_out.append(Image.fromarray(frame))

frames_out[0].save('output.pdf', save_all=True, append_images=frames_out[1:])
```

When using some [sample PDF](http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf), the output looks the same, but with a red rectangle on the first page, and a blue rectangle on the second page.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
PyCharm:       2021.1.1
NumPy:         1.20.2
pdf2image      1.14.0
Pillow:        8.2.0
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. Can I check if the last line `frames_out[0].save(...)` actually requires the file to be saved in a local path? This is something that I am trying to avoid..

Comment: @GohJiaYi I am facing kind of problem, if you have solved please let me know. Thanks

Comment: @Cybermakarov Yes, take a look at the last paragraph of the question (the edit made). I have used the tempfile library which still requires saving the file, but files saved can be deleted easily after for housekeeping purposes.

Comment: hm right but i wanted to do without saving the files into folders.